# Jetty servlet: How can I forward GET request with parameters as POST request with JSON body?

Tags: java, servlets, embedded-jetty

My web clients send GET requests with URL query parameters. The receiving App can only accept POST requests with JSON body. I would like to embed a jetty servlet to the receiving App which converts GET requests to POST request, with url parameters being converted to json format body.

Input GET url for example: http://localhost:8081/?key_1=value_1&key_2=3value_2...&key_n=value_n

Expected POST json payload: {"key_1":"value_1", "key_2":"value_2", ..."key_n":"value_n"}

Could you please illustrate how to implement such functions?

I`ve worked with other programming languages, but am completely new to java. I really really appreciate your help.

Thanks and best regards,
Fischlein

Answer (score 0):

You can read all the query string parameter and put it into HashMap. Then serialize this hashmap using jackson-json api or google gson api.

Jackson Reference Url :

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome

Comment: Thanks.  I found some code, do you think it suits my needs?           public JSONObject requestParamsToJSON(HttpServletRequest req) {
         JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
         Map<String,String[]> params = req.getParameterMap();
         for (Map.Entry<String,String[]> entry : params.entrySet()) {
           String v[] = entry.getValue();
           Object o = (v.length == 1) ? v[0] : v;
           jsonObj.put(entry.getKey(), o);
         }
         return jsonObj;
       }

Answer (score 0):

Read the parameters from the get request, create a json string and post it with a utility library like http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

Comment: Thanks. Could you please demonstrate how to send a post request with org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient? I did not get it right.